# System unauthorized access exception UWP Access to path is denied

Tags: file, uwp

I want to  use
`DirectoryInfo` source `C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Server`:

```
source.GetDirectories();
```

I got `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`:

> 'Access to the path 'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Server' is denied.'

I have UWP application. How to get permission to read and write folders/files from my UWP application?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions  (need also pay attention to if you actually, or the account being used, actually has access to the location you are trying...)

Answer (score 1):

UWP apps were designed to be safer for users to install - by the fact they run in sandbox and do not have most permissions by default the user knows the app can't cause any damage to her PC or data. This includes access to file system - you are allowed to access several specific paths on the PC - including app install location, app data folder. You can request additional locations like libraries, etc.

For arbitrary locations you have two options:

1. Use the `FolderPicker` (see [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers)). User will select the desired folder and you get a `StorageFolder` instance through which you can freely access it. You can even store the permission to this folder over app restarts using `FutureAccessList` (see [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist#Windows_Storage_AccessCache_StorageApplicationPermissions_FutureAccessList)) which will give you a token by which you can retrieve the `StorageFolder` instance in the future.
2. Declare the [`broadFileSystemAccess` capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations). This will give you full access to the filesystem via the `StorageFolder` and `StorageFile` APIs (but not via the classic `System.IO` API). This permission is a restricted one however, so it will be verified during Microsoft Store certification process and your app must have a good reason for actually needing this.